# How do I send multiple query parameters to the api?

Tags: api, oauth, magento2

I'm calling the API to get a list of shipments but I can't seem to page through the results.

The API call is successful with only one query parameter but when I call it with two query parameters, I get the error "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again". I'm including my test code below.

```
<?php
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey       = 'htj8ze6ntr0mz1s4hjxrqeicia8rxgt4';
$consumerSecret    = 'djjzdwfgbbr7ganlkv01qr6p3l7ptvfe';
$accessToken       = '60o0mfrvqnjvin7tjuqsv37arijrqe9e';
$accessTokenSecret = 'caq9wfdx99zaygwgbhw91i9imj89p4zb';

$method = 'GET';

/* test 1 PASS */
//$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
//$qs = ['searchCriteria'=>'all'];

/* test 2 PASS */
//$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
//$qs = ['searchCriteria[pageSize]'=>'10'];

/* test 3 FAIL "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again" */
$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
$qs = ['searchCriteria[pageSize]'=>'10', 'searchCriteria[currentPage]'=>'1'];

$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];
$data = array_merge($data, $qs);

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url .'?' .http_build_query($qs),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo($result);
```

The code includes three tests.

If I uncomment test 1 and comment test 2 and 3, the code works properly and I get a list of shipments.

If I uncomment test 2 and comment test 1 and 3, the code works properly and I get a list of shipments.

If I run the code as is, I get the the message "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again."

I'm running Magento ver. 2.3.2

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to sort the parameters. I have some [client code](https://github.com/patrick-melo/magento-client) anyone is interested.

```
<?php
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

function recursive_sort(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) recursive_sort($value);
    }
    return ksort($array);
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey       = 'htj8ze6ntr0mz1s4hjxrqeicia8rxgt4';
$consumerSecret    = 'djjzdwfgbbr7ganlkv01qr6p3l7ptvfe';
$accessToken       = '60o0mfrvqnjvin7tjuqsv37arijrqe9e';
$accessTokenSecret = 'caq9wfdx99zaygwgbhw91i9imj89p4zb';

$method = 'GET';

/* test 1 PASS */
//$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
//$qs = ['searchCriteria'=>'all'];

/* test 2 PASS */
//$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
//$qs = ['searchCriteria[pageSize]'=>'10'];

/* test 3 FAIL "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again" */
$url = 'http://localhost/rest/V1/shipments/';
$qs = ['searchCriteria'=>['pageSize'=>10,'currentPage'=>1]];

$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];
$data = array_merge($data, $qs);
recursive_sort($data);

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url .'?' .http_build_query($qs),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old, I want to post the answer for future cases.

The code in the question is good, and it helped me a lot.

It is needed to sort parameters by key. Also, please consider that the `searchCriteria` is a multidimensional array. So, the array must be sorted by key recursively.